# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm getting this error every time I try to dispatch my action:

> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async
>   actions.

I've installed `redux-thunk` and without async actions, it's working.

Store config:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import reducers from '../reducers/index';

const logger = createLogger();

export default createStore(reducers, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
```

UI:

```
...
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getCities } from '../../actions/cities';
...
componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      const cities = await this.props.getCities();
      console.log(cities);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`errorhome: ${error}`);
    }
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }
...

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  changeNetworkStatus: () => dispatch(changeNetworkStatus),
  getCities: () => dispatch(getCities),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Action:

```
import database from '../config/utils';

export const GET_CITIES_START = 'GET_CITIES_START';
export const GET_CITIES_FINISHED = 'GET_CITIES_FINISHED';
export const GET_CITIES_ERROR = 'GET_CITIES_ERROR';

const getCititesStart = () => ({ type: GET_CITIES_START });
const getCititesFinished = cities => ({ type: GET_CITIES_FINISHED, cities });
const getCititesError = error => ({ type: GET_CITIES_ERROR, error });

export const getCitites = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(getCititesStart());
  try {
    const cities = [];
    const snap = await database.ref('cities').once('value');
    console.log('snap: ', snap);
    snap.forEach((element) => {
      const city = {
        city: element.key,
        coordinate: element.val().coordinate,
      };
      cities.push(city);
    });
    dispatch(getCititesFinished(cities));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(getCititesError(error));
  }
};
```

EDIT: If I add `logger` to middlewares too, the error message is this:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Thanks for your help!

Comment: For others that end up here. Make sure that you don't have extra `async`s lying around on your functions. This caused me to get the error message in the title. If there's no `await` in the function there should be no `async` in its header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actions are functions that return a object with action's data, that data is a object with a `type` property.

You're dispatching action like this:

```
dispatch(getCities)
```

You should dispatch action like this:

```
dispatch(getCities())
```